# Server side of GSSAPI for sshd and private key authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, gssapi

I'm looking at a way of authenticating users connecting to an SSH daemon. There might be some big misunderstanding in what I'm asking about, but from what I know the GSSAPI can be used as an authentication provider backend for the SSH daemon.

Is there any way of providing user's public key that way? I'd like to retain the private/public key authentication scheme, but provide the user details and keys in a specific way from external processes.

Also, is there any GSSAPI guide which provides programming informations? The only guides I've found so far are very low-level protocol descriptions or server configuration guides for admins... while I'm still missing some practical information about how to approach GSSAPI and how to write something using it (or whether this is possible).

Comment: Are you going to do programming ( this is not clear form your question )? If not, http://serverfault.com/ might be a better place to ask this question. We implemented client-side of GSS-API in code in our SecureBlackbox components for SSH / SFTP (http://www.eldos.com/SecureBlackbox/), if you are interested.

Comment: Yes, I believe I need to implement my own server-side component to do the authentication, so it's a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for kerberos with pkinit support.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4556.txt

Comment: That's pretty cool. Do you know if this is a krb library-specific thing, or can putty somehow use this too?

Comment: putty is nothing to do with pkinit, pkinit matter only when during the initial conversation with kerberos server, ie, AS-REQ and AS-REP. After this your machine will receive a TGT, and this transaction happens during domain login or while doing a kinit. Putty uses this TGT and gets a service ticket and proceed, so a simple kerberos enabled putty is sufficient. I dont know if the windows domain login is enabled for pkinit. But there are some kinit versions support pkinit. http://metavo.metacentrum.cz/en/docs/tokens/windows.html